# Moving data from Javascript/Browser domain to Windows domain

Tags: javascript, browser, websocket

We're looking to integrate with a service that makes it's data available solely via a Javascript API that runs as part of a web page. But, we need to take the data that's returned via the API and have it processed by a standard Win32 application which then communicates with some custom hardware.

The problem is, how best to move the data from the Javascript/Browser domain to the Windows domain?

One possibility is Javascript FileWriter API (Chrome only as I write..?) but I haven't found out how/if the sandboxed files can appear as part of the 'normal' filesystem?

The other solution that I know will work is to use Websockets in the browser to send data to a custom Websocket server that can (for example) save it as a normal file for later processing. But that seems a bit cumbersome?

Is there some other obvious trick I'm missing for exporting data from Javascript within a web page to another application running on the same machine as the browser?

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 Local Storage browser coverage is (fairly) good, I'd consider using that. You'd have to look into the `FileReader` and `FileWriter` spec to see if you can access the files from win32, but it seems possible. Here's a link for more info: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage

Also, look at this previous answer for more clarification on how one would use Local Storage:
[Can the OS as well as javascript/HTML5 access localstorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677780/can-the-os-as-well-as-javascript-html5-access-localstorage)

Comment: As the answer you link to says, local storage formats are unspecified and liable to change. I expect chrome uses sqlite, but I'm not sure I can bet on that...